# Boostrap grid system in small screen problem

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create responsive web layout where i should have different view in different devices screen.

1. 2 rows 6 columns (large screen, iPad Pro and other devices)
2. 3 rows 4 columns (iPhone 6/7/8 plus)
3. 4 rows 3 columns (iphone 6/7/8 and smaller device)

this is what i have tried

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 ">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="  col-xs-2 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="  col-xs-2 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="  col-xs-2 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-xs-2 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="  col-xs-2 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="  col-xs-2 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-xs-2 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="  col-xs-2 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class=" col-xs-2 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="  col-xs-2 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

i've 2 row 6 colum in big screens but in iPhone 6/7/8 plus and iphone 6/7/8 and smaller device i get only one column.
i don't know how to fix it, hope my problem is clear :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap layout axis is divided by 12

you probably need to replace this in your div class attributes

```
 class="  col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"
```

you also can use vanilla CSS to target different screen sizes

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

where for max-width in different devices you can use:

320px — 480px: Mobile devices.

481px — 768px: iPads, Tablets.

769px — 1024px: Small screens, laptops.

1025px — 1200px: Desktops, large screens.

1201px and more — Extra large screens, TV.

Comment: that's not what i want at all, i get one column in mobile devices, Tablet and iPads.

Comment: Assuming extra small screen (mobile) if you use col-xs-4 you should get  3 columns ( 3 * 4 = 12)

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the available pre-set breakpoints in Bootstrap 4.5 here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

To summarize:

- Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)

  - media query: none
  - column class name: `col-*`
- Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)

  - media query: `@media (min-width: 576px)`
  - column class name: `col-sm-*`
- Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)

  - media query: `@media (min-width: 768px)`
  - column class name: `col-md-*`
- Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)

  - media query: `@media (min-width: 992px)`
  - column class name: `col-lg-*`
- Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)

  - media query: `@media (min-width: 1200px)`
  - column class name: `col-xl-*`

And Bootstrap Grid system is using 12 columns per row: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#grid-options

In other words, to construct what you want, you would need:

- 3 columns per row (iphone 6/7/8 and smaller device)

  - 12 / 3 = 4
  - column class name: `col-4`
- 4 columns per row (iPhone 6/7/8 plus)

  - 12 / 4 = 3
  - column class name: `col-sm-3`
- 6 columns per row (large screen, iPad Pro and other devices)

  - 12 / 6 = 2
  - column class name: `col-md-2`

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            </img />
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/aoc3ksve/3/

You can use `.img-fluid` on images to get responsive images too:

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/aoc3ksve/5/

Comment: thanks for explaination but your code doesn't solve my problem . i get 3 rows and 5 columns which i didn't want. what i realy want is 3 rows 4 columns (iPhone 6/7/8 plus)
 3. 4 rows 3 columns (iphone 6/7/8 and smaller device) and in other screen 2 rows 6 columns

Comment: @ted: you're using Bootstrap 4 aren't you? There are some breaking changes between Bootstrap 3 and 4, and replacement of `col-xs-*` to `col-*` is one of them. Have you seen my demo links up there? If you're indeed using Bootstrap 3, please update your tag from bootstrap-4 to bootstrap-3.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap3 grid system has four classes:

xs (for phones - screens less than 768px wide)

sm (for tablets - screens equal to or greater than 768px wide)

md (for small laptops - screens equal to or greater than 992px wide)

lg (for laptops and desktops - screens equal to or greater than 1200px wide)

```css
.img-responsive {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Here 414px and 736px are width of iPhone 6/7/8 plus */

@media only screen and (min-width: 414px) and (max-width: 736px) {
  .col-xs-4 {
     width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 ">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow/96/cat-purr-icon.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'm geting only 2 columns in mobile devices and that's not what i want. what exactly i want is 3 rows 4 columns (iPhone 6/7/8 plus)
4 rows 3 columns (iphone 6/7/8 and smaller device)

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check once

Comment: it's working thank you vary much.